# set a variable to a line within a text file containing a known value?

Tags: batch-file

I'm having problems trying to create a batch script that will search through a txt file in a directory for a value "drawing_revision" and then take the line from this and extract the revision and set it as a variable I can use as a prefix on file names.

DRAWING_REVISION                 00                   TYPE: String

Has anyone done anything like this before? there doesn't seem to be much on using the line within the text file as a variable rather than the file name.

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 1):

You could try a FOR-LOOP

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=2" %%a IN (`findstr DRAWING_REVISION myfile.txt`) do (
  echo Draw-Rev = %%a
)
```